# iText tables - how to keep multi row cells on one page?

Tags: java, itext

I'm creating a table in iText that lists events for a date. If there are mutliple events for a date, I set the rowspan property of the date-cell to the number of events. I'm currently using a row for each event, since I want to display additional info for the event and want to keep everything aligned.
Basicly my table can look like this:

```
 Date   | Event     | Details
--------+-----------+---------------
 date 1 | event 1   | details 1
--------+-----------+---------------
 date 2 | event 2 1 | more 
        |           | details 2 1
        +-----------+---------------
        | event 2 2 | details 2 2
--------+-----------+---------------
```

the cell containing `date 2` has a rowspan of 2.

I add the table using `ColumnText.go()` in a loop.

If I write the table to the document and there is only enough space left for `event 2 1`, `event 2 2` goes to the new page. How can I force a new page before adding `date 2`?

Using `PdfPTable.setSplitLate(true)` doesn't seem to affect multi row cells. Neither does setting the fixed height of the `date 2` cell to the combined heights of the two rows.

- one solution would be to use nested tables for column 2 and 3 (and treat column 2 and 3 as one column)
- another solution, that doesn't work correctly in the version of iText I'm using would be to use `PdfPTable.writeSelectedRows()` and write only the (combined) rows that fit on the page. the problem is, that this way the row span is ignored and `Date` cells look like tey only span one row.

Are there any other ways?

Comment: one possible solution in current iText could be `PdfPTable.keepRowsTogether(int [])` - unfortunately it's not aviable in the version of iText I have to use

Comment: which version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a table for each row and use `PdfPTable.setKeepTogether(true)` which works in even iText 2.1.7, though I wouldn't recommend staying with that version.  Here is an example, where `outputFile` is a File type variable where the PDF file is being created.

```
Document document = new Document(new Rectangle(620, 150));
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(outputFile));

document.open();

PdfPTable headerRow = new PdfPTable(3);
headerRow.setKeepTogether(true);
headerRow.addCell("Date");
headerRow.addCell("Event");
headerRow.addCell("Details");

PdfPTable firstRow = new PdfPTable(3);
firstRow.setKeepTogether(true);
firstRow.addCell("date 1");
firstRow.addCell("event 2 1");
firstRow.addCell("more\ndetails 2 1");

PdfPTable secondRow = new PdfPTable(3);
secondRow.setKeepTogether(true);
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("date 2"));
cell.setRowspan(2);
secondRow.addCell(cell);
secondRow.addCell("event 2 1");
secondRow.addCell("more\ndetails 2 1");
secondRow.addCell("event 2 2");
secondRow.addCell("details 2 2");

document.add(headerRow);
document.add(firstRow);
document.add(secondRow);

document.close();
```

Honestly though, I think the nested table is the better idea.

Comment: Unrelated specifically to the question, if you are using iText 2.1.7, I would take a look here http://itextpdf.com/tags/itext-217 to read more about that particular version.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30, 30, 100, 150);
        document.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
        writer.PageEvent = new ITextEvents();
        document.Open();
        iTextSharp.text.Font fntHead2 = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bfntHead, 11, 1, BaseColor.BLACK);
        Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
        Chunk glue = new Chunk(new VerticalPositionMark());
        Phrase ph1 = new Phrase();

        Paragraph main = new Paragraph();
        ph1.Add(new Chunk("Left Side", fntHead2)); 
        ph1.Add(glue); // Here I add special chunk to the same phrase.    
        ph1.Add(new Chunk("Right Side", fntHead2)); 
        para.Add(ph1);
        document.Add(para);
```